# Results based on user skills

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a column in the `users` table which is named `skills` with a type of `VARCHAR` and a value that's `implod`ed by PHP. e.g. `1,2,3,4,5`

I'm trying to make a list of works, the works have the same skills set (*different IDs*), each `work` has its own skills column in the same format of the previous one. e.g. `2,6,5,3,7`

So I want to compare these two columns with a query to see if a work has all or some skills of a user if yes then display it.

As already posted topics over the community I found some solutions around with `FIND_IN_SET` or multiple `LIKE` statements, but actually they don't fit my case.

As I'm not a query fan so what could be the best or the good practice of this comparison?

Comment: Check my final SQL. Short and clean ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you not to keep skill ids imploded like that. Keep 5 tables.

1. users (userid, name)
2. skills (skillid, skillname)
3. usersskills (skillid, userid)
4. works (workid, name)
5. workskills (workid, skillid)

You'll have clean and expandable structure and easy to pull data.

SQL to get skills of a user is

```
SELECT skillid, skillname FROM Skills INNER JOIN UsersSkills ON Skills.skillid = UsersSkills.skillid WHERE UserSkills.userid = 3
```

SQL to get skills of a work

```
SELECT skillid, skillname FROM skills INNER JOIN workskills ON skills.skillid = workskills.skillid WHERE workskills.workid = 1
```

Let's assume we have these two tables

```
usersskills              worksskills
+--------+---------+     +--------+-------+
|skillid | userid  |     |skillid |workid |
+--------+---------+     +--------+-------+
| 1      | 1       |     | 1      | 3     |
| 2      | 1       |     | 2      | 3     |
| 3      | 1       |     | 3      | 3     |
| 4      | 1       |     | 4      | 3     |
| 1      | 2       |     | 5      | 3     |
| 2      | 2       |     +--------+--------
+--------+---------+
```

Here we have 2 users, first one having 4 skills, second one having 2 skills. Our work (id 3) requires 5 different skills.

Here are the qualifications of the users for this work.

```
+--------+-------------+
|userid  |scorepercent |
+--------+-------------+
|1       |80           |
|2       |40           |
+--------+-------------+
```

User 1 qualifies the work 80%, user 2 qualifies 40%

**SQL (Short and Clean)**

*All users ordered by their score*

```
select 
    userid,
    (count(skillid) * 100 / (select count(*) from skillswork where workid = 3)) as score
from
    skillsuser
where
    skillid in (select skillid from skillswork where workid = 3)
group by
    userid
order by 
    score desc
```

*If you don't need percentages and just a simple SQL*

```
select 
    userid,
    count(skillid) as score
from
    skillsuser
where
    skillid in (select skillid from skillswork where workid = 3)
group by
    userid
order by 
    score desc
```

*Single targeted user*

```
select 
    userid,
    (count(skillid) * 100 / (select count(*) from skillswork where workid = 3)) as score
from
    skillsuser
where
    skillid in (select skillid from skillswork where workid = 3)
    and
    userid = 1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8485e/11/0)

Comment: Yes - although, reminiscent of the pen island catastrophe, maybe an amended naming strategy

Comment: Nice Explanations! However do u mean `worksskills` by skillswork and `usersskills` by skillsuser?

Comment: @revo yeah I'm not the best in English or naming the tables ;)

Comment: @revo yep you are right. Edited my answer now it should work properly

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is to change your schema. Don't store multiple values in one column. The relationship between users and skills is a "many-to-many" relationship. For any many-to-many relationship, you should use three tables:

```
users -- one record for each user
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 1  | Bob  |
| 2  | Joe  |
| 3  | Ken  |
+----+------+

skills -- one record for each possible skill
+----+-------------+
| id | name        |
+----+-------------+
| 1  | PHP         |
| 2  | CSS         |
| 3  | JS          |
| 4  | MySQL       |
+----+-------------+

userSkills -- relational table that maps skills to users
+--------+---------+
| userId | skillId |
+--------+---------+
| 1      | 1       |
| 1      | 2       |
| 1      | 3       |
| 1      | 4       |
| 2      | 2       |
| 2      | 3       |
| 2      | 4       |
| 3      | 1       |
| 3      | 4       |
+--------+---------+
```

Now, when you want to find out Joe's skills, you can do this query:

```
SELECT
    s.name
FROM
    users u
    INNER JOIN userSkills us
        ON u.id = us.userId
    INNER JOIN skills s
        ON us.skillId = s.id
WHERE
    u.name = 'Joe'
```

The relationship between works and skills is also a many-to-many relationship. We'll need two more tables, since we already have the `skills` table.

```
works
+----+-----------------------+
| id | name                  |
+----+-----------------------+
| 1  | Client-side developer |
| 2  | Server-side developer |
| 3  | All-around developer  |
+----+-----------------------+

workSkills
+--------+---------+
| workId | skillId |
+--------+---------+
| 1      | 2       |
| 1      | 3       |
| 2      | 1       |
| 2      | 4       |
| 3      | 1       |
| 3      | 2       |
| 3      | 3       |
| 3      | 4       |
+--------+---------+
```

So now you can find out all skills needed for a Server-side developer via a query like this:

```
SELECT
    s.name
FROM
    works w
    INNER JOIN workSkills ws
        ON w.id = ws.workId
    INNER JOIN skills s
        ON ws.skillId = s.id
WHERE
    w.name = 'Server-side developer'
```

---

Now comes the tricky part. Getting a list of users for a given work. The following query will give you a list of users that have skills in common with the specified work. The more skills they have for that work, the higher their score:

```
SELECT
    u.name,
    COUNT(s.name) AS score
FROM
    users u
    INNER JOIN userSkills us
        ON u.id = us.userId
    INNER JOIN skills s
        ON us.skillId = s.id
    INNER JOIN workSkills ws
        ON s.id = ws.skillId
    INNER JOIN works w
        ON ws.workId = w.id
  WHERE
      w.name = 'Server-side developer'
  GROUP BY
      u.name
  ORDER BY
      score DESC
```

Outputs:

```
+------+-------+
| name | score |
+------+-------+
| Bob  | 2     | -- Bob has all four skills, but only PHP and MySQL are relevant
| Ken  | 2     | -- Ken has PHP and MySQL skills, same as this work requires
| Joe  | 1     | -- Joe has CSS, JS, and MySQL skills...only MySQL is relevant
+------+-------+
```

## [SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8485e/2)